# Regex optional match operator: how to apply to a string of characters?

Tags: python, ruby, regex, perl

I am facing an issue when trying to apply the following regular expression:

`(1234).*?(abcd)?`

To the below string:

`1234567abcd`

My expectation is that the above should produce two matches:

1. 1234
2. abcd

However, this does not work.  You might suggest "well, just remove the trailing `?` character?" -- but I want this second pattern to be optional.

How is this done?

To reiterate:

`(1234).*?(abcd)`

... gives the desired result, but my searched string won't always contain `abcd`.

In case anyone is wondering, this is a simplified example of the bigger picture problem.  I'll explain that if needed.

====

I think this problem needs additional clarification.  Here is a more complete example of what I am trying to do, in ruby.

Given the following two "doctored up" lines from my logfile:

```
Aug 28 00:00:05 app-system-1 app-prod[7660]: Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 24.6ms | ActiveRecord: 66.1ms)
Aug 28 00:05:06 app-system-1 app-prod[10639]: Completed 302 Found in 81ms (ActiveRecord: 74.6ms)
```

I have tried to compile a regex in ruby as follows:

```
d=Regexp.new('(?<timestamp>\w{1,3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*(?<in>in [0-9]*).*(?<views>Views: [0-9]*).*(?<activerecord>ActiveRecord: [0-9]*)')
```

Obviously in some cases the the 'views' text will be included, in other rows, it is not present.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
v=d.match(line)
if !v.nil?
    puts v[:timestamp]+ " " + v[:in] + " " + v[:views] + " " + v[:activerecord]
```

This is obviously an incomplete example but hopefully this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what you want, at least not clearly, but I think you want the following:

- When given `...1234567abcd...` as input, `1234567abcd` should be matched, and `1234` and `abcd` should be captured.
- When given `...1234567abce...` as input, `1234` should be matched, `1234` should be captured.

If so, you can use:

```
/(1234)(?:.*?(abcd))?/s
```

I hate using the greediness modifier. It's used to avoid matching certain sequences, but there's no guarantee that it won't. I'd use the following instead:

```
/
   (1234)
   (?:
      (?:(?!abcd).)*    # Safer than .*?
      (abcd)
   )?
/sx
```

Comment: I added some more clarification to the 'problem' at hand in my original problem statement.  I think you probably are on the right track to helping me solve this.  Can you take a look above? :)  Thanks!

Comment: You should really do it in steps. 1) extract the parens, then 2) split the contents on " | ", then 3) split the key from the value.

Answer (score 1):

Anchoring the regular expression works:

```
/(1234).*?(abcd)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to ikegami but simpler I think:

```
/(1234)(?:(?!abcd).)*(abcd)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `(a|)` is roughly equivalent to `(a)?` we can use:

```
(1234).*?(abcd|)
```

To force the regex engine to inspect the `abcd` first. The default for an optional rule with `?` is to assume it is absent (that is equivalent to `(|abcd)`). This default behaviour is important to ensure that the regex terminates (faster).

Comment: No, `(a|)` is effectively the same as `(a)?`.  It will match anywhere because it can always match nothing.

Comment: uh, that doesn't change anything. Like `(?:a|)`, `a?` tries to match `"a"` before it tries to match `""`.

Comment: in perl, ? prefers to match rather than not match, equivalent to `{0,1}`.  ?? is the version that prefers not matching, equivalent to `{0,1}?`.  I would be interested to hear it if this is not true in python or ruby (the other languages indicated in the tags).

Comment: @Alan Moore: in perl, `(a|)` and `(a)?` differ only in that the former can capture `a` or an empty string while the latter can capture `a` or undef.  This is a subtle difference, but a difference nonetheless.

Comment: @ysth: I know. I just meant, like you and @ikegami, that `?` is **not** non-greedy. (That applies to Python, Ruby, and every other flavor I'm familiar with, BTW.  PHP has the `/U` modifier which makes all quantifiers non-greedy, but greedy is the default.)  Furthermore, greediness or non-greediness is not relevant; what matters is that `(a|)`--just like `(a)?`--will match wherever it's applied because it can match nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should really do it in steps.

```
if (my ($ts, $dur, $breakdown) = /
   ^
   (\w{3}[ ]\d{1,2}[ ]\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)
   .*?
   in[ ]([0-9]*)ms
   .*?
   \( ([^()]*) \)
/xs) {
   my %breakdown = map /^([^:]+): (.*)ms/, split /\s*\|\s*/, $breakdown;
   say join ', ',
      $ts,
      $dur,
      $breakdown{Views} // '--',
      $breakdown{ActiveRecord} // '--';
}
```